# Store ListView data C#

Tags: c#, listview, datastore

I'm trying to make me a little program in C # (using Visual Studio 2010) to keep track of the films that I keep on my computer. The interface is just a ListView with 7 Columns and a Add button. Add button opens a opendialog and allows me to select the video file. Click on Open and then goes info about the file or files in the ListView table.

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me what would be the best method to store the listview table. So all info that i put into the listview over the time will always appear when i start the program. Maybe like what do I do to get a similar substation such as iTunes, when I add music file and exit the program then run the program later the file  will be there not empty listview like i get at this state.

Should i use StreamWriter and textfile or is there a better way?

excuse me if this is complicated. My English not good enough.
I am not an experienced programmer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something as simple as what you're doing, I serialize to an XML file, and then Deserialize from the same XML file every time the application opens.

If you list of movies gets too big, consider moving to some light-weight database.

Comment: My code is all in the Form1.cs. Dont fully understand how I can use this XmlSerialize. I Understand the example at msdn site but i have no class like OrderedItems to put in XmlSerializer serializer = 
      new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderedItem)); Let me know if you dont understand what i am talking about and if you would like to see the code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdxxw552.aspx

Comment: I would suggest that you factor out your code into separate classes- possibly even into a different project within your solution.  Otherwise, you're stuck writing custom XML code- which doesn't suck, but it's not as easy as calling the serializer.

Comment: Ok, but i dont understand how i would factor out my ListView to another class since I design the interface with Visual Studio and all details about it is in InitializeComponent(); But i will keep trying. Tried few things this evening but all failed. Errors or empty xml files.

Comment: I was going to post some of this anyway, just for fun, but check out edi-fication.blogspot.com for some quick tips.

Comment: Thank you. Gave me some ideas but still little confused about the factoring. Want to ask about few things. You dont have to answer them if you dont have time. In Movie class I should implement methods that get the info from the files i want to put into my listview?

Comment: Second im not sure what Library and LibraryManager do. Still confused where I set up my listview, how it looks and set up the amount of columns and so on and how i use your idea, the class library, to put data about my video files to the listview. Like I said Im not an experienced programmer and i think that part(store the data) is the hardest part of this program. But again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using an [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to easily save to an xml file, then load (deserialize) from it when your program starts.  I've used this successfully in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give another option besides XML.  You could use a SQLite database if you are familiar with writing SQL statements.  It integrates quite nicely and gives you a relational database to play with.

Two implementations:

- http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/
- http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `xml document` and could put your data in xml file. `XmlDocument` class provides easy way to manipulate and read nodes from xml. But use `XmlDocument` when your file is not large. MSDN post about [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).